# GPodder cannot download podcasts for some feeds

Tags: download, podcasts, podcatcher

I try to use GPodder to download podcasts. For some feeds I cannot downloads any podcasts with  error messages like:

[image]

The text in gpodder log-file for this error is:

```
2013-01-23 18:54:41,322 [gpodder.gtkui.main] ERROR: While downloading Особое мнение : Дмитрий Быков 
Traceback (most recent call last):  
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\gPodder\src\gpodder\gtkui\main.py", line 2760, in download_episode_list
    task = download.DownloadTask(episode, self.config)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\gPodder\src\gpodder\download.py", line 630, in __init__
    open(self.tempname, 'w').close()
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'F:\\podcasts\\Downloads\\  () _  \\2013-01-16-osoboe-1708.mp3.partial'
```

I guess gPodder has some problems with language encodings. It cannot create valid folder name for some feeds, so files cannot be written to this folder.
 
How to fix this problem? *(Cause I don't want to return to Juice podcast aggregator)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

gPodder stores podcast-feeds info in a file named *Database*. This is a SQLite database file and can be edited with any appropriate software (I use [SQLite Browser](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sqlitebrowser/)). This database file includes field named *download folder*. After editing this field for buggy podcast feeds the problem is disappeared.

***UPDATE:*** File *Database* is located in a folder with podcasts or in `%USERPROFILE%\Documents\gPodder` (Ubuntu: `~/gPodder`). Make a backup before editing.

Answer (score 1):

Rename your podcast in list  by simple rmb -> "Podcast settings", from something non-english to english.
Have same problem ( with same "Echo Moscow" :) ), works for me.
This create correct folder for your podcast